# Send email via python in c++

Tags: python, c++, email, command-line

my question is whether I can send an email via python in a c++ program.

That is my actual python script.

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
# From
fromaddr = "...@gmail.com"
# To
toaddr = "..."
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
# subject
msg['Subject'] = "..."
# Text
body = "..."
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
#smtplib import
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login("username", "password")
text = msg.as_string()
#send email
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
```

My plan ist it, that I will open python and import the script via the commandline in the programm.
Is there a better way to do it?

The problem is that c++ open via system("python") the commandline, but now I have to write import mail.py in the command line.
Can I do this automaticly with an other order? I will open python, import mail and quit with one order. Is that possible?

Thank You!

Comment: So you want to run the above python script with a C++ script?

Comment: This might be of interest to you: https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html. Rather than running a separate python process from your C++ process, you can actually embed the python interpreter within your existing process. It may be more complicated than you need though.

Comment: Right, I want to run the python script with a C++ script. @wnnmaw

Comment: system("python script.py <arguments>");

Answer (score 0):

Here is the program for an email.

```
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.login(email, password)
smtpserver.sendmail(email, recipient, text)
print 'Message Sent!'
smtpserver.close()
```

The variables: email is your email address, password is the password to your email, recipient is the receiver of the email, and text is the text to send.